# switchIfEmpty equivalent in Flow?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Im migrating my app from RxJava into Flow and cant find an equivalent for `switchIfEmpty`. I basically have three sources that i want to consecutively call if the previous one has not emitted anything.

like this:

```
source1.getData().switchIfEmpty(source2.getData()).switchIfEmpty(source3.getData())
```

Is this achievable with Flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything similar for flows out of the box. We can very easily create such operator by ourselves:

```kotlin
suspend fun main() {
    val f0 = flowOf<Int>()
    val f1 = flowOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
    val f2 = flowOf(5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0)

    f1.ifEmpty(f2).collect { println(it) } // 1, 2, 3, 4
    f0.ifEmpty(f2).collect { println(it) } // 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0
    f0.ifEmpty(f0).ifEmpty(f1).collect { println(it) } // 1, 2, 3, 4
}

fun <T> Flow<T>.ifEmpty(default: Flow<T>): Flow<T> = onEmpty { emitAll(default) }
```

I named it `ifEmpty`, because `switch` doesn't feel very natural for flows. Also, there are similar `ifEmpty` functions for collections and sequences.

Returned flow uses the closest common supertype of both flows.